# Transfer fluid from one cylinder to another

Tags: matlab

I'm trying unsuccessfully to simulate a flow of ink through a system of many rollers. As each roller turns the ink is split depending on a given ratio (say 0.5).
I have managed to get the rollers in the system plotted by taking some user data but i'm now completely stuck on how to proceed! Some of these rollers will be in contact with more than one roller and as such the ink will be split equally and then halved again as it reaches the next roller in the line.

can anyone suggest a function for declaring these connecting positions and keeping track of the ink split after a certain number of system revolutions?...I've tried this in python using the dictionaries although I can't seem to translate this to matlab particularly well.

What I have thus far is in Python:

```
for i in range(num_rollers): 
    roller_data() 

for i in range(0,num_rollers): 
    for j in range(Rollers[i]['segments']): 
        Rollers[i]['ink'].append(0) 

# Initialise nips 
Nips = [{} for i in range(num_nips)] 
Nips[0] = {'rollers': [0, 1], 'locations': []} 
Nips[1] = {'rollers': [1, 2], 'locations': []} 
Nips[2] = {'rollers': [2, 3], 'locations': []}
```

Comment: For starters, you could share your current (even if non-working) code. Otherwise you're just asking to implement a solution from scratch.

Comment: apologies for this, i didn't want to confuse the issue as my code is still in python...here is a cut down version, notice that 'nips' refers to the conenction point between the rollers:

Comment: Don't post code in comments, not if you want people to read it.  Edit your question.

Comment: @richyo1000: Comments screw up the formatting of code, which is especially annoying with Python code. I've edited your question now, but in the future, please include the minimum code required to reproduce the problem, or in any case, [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: Thanks for that! I also just submitted a revised version including some python code but it hasn't posted for some reason!I can do it again if anyone would like to see it, otherwise any help is massively appreciated! Cheers

Comment: @richyo1000 How would you represent the location of the rollers? Would it be on a 2-D plane or in 3-D space?

Comment: it's in 2D, i'm just treating them as circles located using polar coords. not sure i can post images here but there's 15 of them in fixed positions and they transfer ink to the next in line as they rotate (they also retain a certain amount of ink after the split). Currently, I take user input for roller diameter, position, etc...and plot that. Looks ok but there's zero functionality!

Comment: I worry that you might be over defining your problem.  Is there anyway you can simplify it?  Also can you point us to a working implementation of a similar problem even if its in a different language?

Comment: Hi @slayton, I think basically what i'm looking for is a function which will keep track of how much ink is on a particular roller.I'm trying to define the connections between rollers in terms of the angle and would like to know how much ink is transferred after n number of revolutions...Unfortunately I've searched for weeks and haven't discovered anything similar!I fear you may be right though about my over defining the problem, if i could post an image here of what i'm looking at it could maybe help but i'm not sure how to do that on these forums....

Comment: What is your end goal? Can you assume that each roller simply loses a percentage or its ink, or must the loss depend on the configuration.  If this is for more than simple theoretical purposes I'd start by taking some measurements of ink loss on rollers (if I could get my hands on them).  When it comes to defining complex models like this you really have to base yourself in data.

Comment: To be honest i reckon a spreadsheet may well do most of what i'm asking but unfortunately that isn't what i've been asked to do...Let's say i have 10 units of ink going into the system, this then is split 50/50 between each roller consecutively.the path isn't necessarily direct, it splits in more than one place.finally, there are four rollers in contact with a big cylinder each laying down a proportion of ink, it's those numbers that i'm after really.mathematically i'd just use a geometric series but i think i need functions to rotate the rollers and keep track of the ink...cheers @slayton

Comment: oh yeah, unfortunately i can't measure the ink on the machine, i don't have a test machine i can use so i suppose that's why this simulator may come in handy, i intend to use it to test theoretical roller arrangements at some point but just to get something working on a standard system would be a good start!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't specify the exact model of your rollers, I'll represent them in polar coordinations, *i.e.* with a center point and a radius. The ink on each roller will be represented by an additional value, for example:

```
% # Initial state
C = [0, 0; -0.8, -0.6; 1, 0];  % # Roller centers (x, y)
R = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5];           % # Roller radii (r)
ink = [1, 0, 0];               % # Amount of ink on each roller
N = numel(R);                  % # Amount of rollers
```

Here there's ink only on roller #1 (I chose these values arbitrarily, so they can be changed, of course). For your convenience, you can draw the rollers like so:

```
% # Draw the rollers
figure, hold on
ang = 0:0.1:(2 * pi);
for i = 1:N
    plot(C(i, 2) + R(i) * cos(ang), C(i, 1) + R(i) * sin(ang))
    text(C(i, 2), C(i, 1), num2str(i))
end
title('Ink rollers'), axis image
```

That should produce the following image:

[image: Rollers]
I'll leave it up to you to draw the ink on each roller :P

**And now to business:**

1) First we find all connected rollers:

```
% # Find connected rollers
isconn = @(m, n)(sum(([1, -1] * C([m, n], :)) .^ 2) - sum(R([m, n])) .^ 2 < eps);
[Y, X] = meshgrid(1:N, 1:N);
conn = reshape(arrayfun(isconn, X(:), Y(:)), N, N) - eye(N);
```

This produces a matrix in which each element in the position (*i*, *j*) is 1 if roller *i* and roller *j* are connected, and 0 if not. In this example, we get:

```
conn =

     0     1     1
     1     0     0
     1     0     0
```

2) The next step is to simulate the ink flow by running a predetermined amount of iterations. In each iteration we simulate one revolution of each roller, *i.e.* we go over each roller and split the ink equally between itself and its neighbors.

```
% # Simulate ink flow for a number of revolutions
disp([sprintf('Initial state:\t\t'), '[', num2str(ink), ']'])
revolutions = 3;
for ii = 1:revolutions
    new_ink = zeros(size(ink));

    % # Iterate over each roller
    for jj = 1:N
        if (ink(jj) > 0)
            delta_ink = ink(jj) / (sum(conn(jj, :)) + 1);
            idx = [jj, find(conn(jj, :))]; % # roller jj and its neighbors
            new_ink(idx) = new_ink(idx) + delta_ink;
        end
    end
    ink = new_ink;
    disp([sprintf('Revolution #%d:\t\t', ii), '[', num2str(ink), ']'])
end
```

I apologize that I haven't put much effort into optimizing these loops by vectorization. Anyway, these are the amounts of ink on each roller in each revolution:

> `Initial state:     [1  0  0]
>
>   Revolution #1:     [0.33333     0.33333     0.33333]
>
>   Revolution #2:     [0.44444     0.27778     0.27778]
>
>   Revolution #3:     [0.42593     0.28704     0.28704]`

Obviously, you can easily put this code into a function that returns the last state of the rollers, or any other output of your choice. Moreover, you can also revise the algorithm to handle different splitting ratios depending on the radii of the rollers. Good luck!

Comment: !are you in the UK?I owe you many many beers!!The image you produced is surprisingly close to what i have plotted!i've been stuck on this for over a week now and you solved it in an hour, thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help :) Actually, I've just returned from a visit to the UK and Ireland! Next time I'm there, I'll hold you to it! :)