# Emulsion split between rollers

Tags: matlab

Here is a real simplification of [my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229360/transfer-fluid-from-one-cylinder-to-another/13234798):

I have numerous interconnected rollers with ink on one of them initially, and they rotate relative to one another. The ink is shared 50/50 between rollers as they rotate. Some rollers have more than one connection and so the order which the ink split takes place is important. Here's a visualization:

[image]

I'm basically looking for something which will allow the program to iterate through the connections in order.
I had thought something like:

```
for each roller
    if number_of_connections > 2  % # more than one connection for roller
        % # Iterate through connections sequentially, depending on the direction
        % # of rotation
    end
end
```

Comment: Hi. How is your "order" defined, _i.e._ how is one roller prioritized over another, when your iterate over all connections?

Comment: Morning Eitan, there is no priority as such, i tried to post an image unsuccessfully...Say i have a roller connected to 3 others at different points on the circumference (i.e. measured from the vertical we have 35°,127°,285°), if this roller is rotating clockwise then i would like the program to recognise that where there are more than 2 connections the ink split is carried out sequentially. The program as it currently stands splits the ink equally no matter how many connections there are, in reality the ink split will occur sequentially depending on the direction of rotation on each roller.

Comment: All the rollers are driven by surface friction except one so there will always be an (sometimes more than one) anti-clockwise roller in contact with a clockwise roller. The code you initially provided is excellent by the way and i think it may the case that that code can be modified for what i need, i just don't fully understand it! i'm specifically thinking of the part you labelled as % # iterate over each roller. thanks very much for your help/interest anyway Eitan, you've already got me further than i would have been by now!

Comment: Ok, so what you're saying is that if the roller rotates clockwise, then then ink is in a clockwise sequence between the connected rollers. But what would be the starting point? Which roller gets the split ink first? (P.S: I've edited your question and prettified it a bit)

Comment: Ah, the ink only enters the system at one point and is then smoothed/shared between the rollers. i guess i need to define a 'zero' position for the rollers. the starting point would be where the rollers connect, i.e. roll1 connects to roll2 at position 270° on roll1 and position 35° roll2 (just an example) so the starting position for roll2 is 35°. if roll2 is connected to roll3,4 and 5 and rotates clockwise then i would like the ink splits to take place in the order in which each roll is encountered.

Comment: in the image you provided initially, imagine we have another roller connecting to 1 with the ink coming into roll1 at just before roll3, clockwise we would see the transfer as: roll3-imaginary roller-roll2. this is much more difficult to explain than i thought, i hope you get it. i think the program you provided does a lot of the work, i just need to break out where there are more complicated connections and perfom a slightly different loop i think. I'm really struggling with this abstraction!

Comment: thanks for sorting the link out as well, i really thought i had it that time!

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, but I'm missing a few "ground rules" for the ink splitting. I'm still thinking about what is missing though :) How is the ink split between rollers then? Let's suppose for now that all neighboring rollers are of the same diameter, and let's put them in a queue, the first in the queue getting the ink first. Does the first roller in the queue get the same amount of ink like the last?

Comment: if you search inker system in google you should get a better idea of what i'm dealing with, the first image result is fairly similar to the type of system i'm trying to simulate except i have more rollers where there is more than one connection...i would post an image of my exact system except the .png doesn't upload for some reason (i have tried!)

Comment: Could you address the question in my last comment? It would really clarify the entire picture. By the way, here are instructions of [how to upload a picture to a post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post), just in case...

Comment: the ink comes in only at a single position on the 'first' roller. from here it is transferred equally between the rollers in contact, so roll2=roll1/2 and roll3 = roll2/2, etc... the difficulty for me i think is where the split becomes dependant on the direction of rotation. So initially only one roller has ink on it, the ink is then transferred between rollers as the ink on the surface of the initial roller moves through the connection point on the next roller in line. i hope this helps is what you were asking!

Comment: Then your problem is not the ratio of splitting (the ink remains evenly split, like in my former), but rather the _order_ of splitting. So, in the "Iterate over each roller" loop, instead of the loop arbitrarily going throw the rollers in the order they are defined in the code, you want to iterate over the rollers depending on the direction of rotation? But again, just to make clear, the ink is still split evenly between connected rollers.

Comment: yes i think you've got it Eitan! i'm assuming an equal split just for simplicty but yes, say the first roller in the system rotates anticlockwise then all the other rollers must rotate in a relative direction. i don't think the diameter would have much effect apart from the actual plotting of any images so yeah, i think you understand my system now!i'll be doing this hopefully for many different configurations with a view to making some useful comparisons!

Comment: Implementing it is not that difficult (but can prove to be tedious). You should create a binary array with the direction of rotation of each roller, for each roller compute the angles of the connected rollers and deduce their queue order. Then you modify the loop to iterate over each roller according to its direction of rotation and its queue of neighbors. I'll think about it, and try to come up with a short and clever way to do that easily.

Comment: Thanks very much Eitan, I've tried various ways (creating position matrix for each roller then using a larger rotation matrix) but everything i have tried logically fails...the code you initially provided works really well - at the time of asking for help i had not considered that i might need more functionality hence the position i know find myself in!thanks for your help

Comment: Your problem is actually very interesting. I'll try to work out a solution this week when time allows...

Comment: @EitanT, thanks for your help on this!I'm working on a functional spec for what i think the simulator should show and i agree - the problem is a good one!I'm also working on a solution, i think i was actually further on when i was writing in Python but now i spent a load of money on matlab i'm determined to try and use the thing!The way i'm thinking now is to have a fixed resolution of segments on one of the rollers(probably the largest) and all the others should be a relative, integer, ratio of this so the segments match as the system rotates.This solution also has it's problems!thanks!

Comment: @EitanT hey, happy new year and all that stuff! hope you had a good one! I was wondering, I haven't closed this down as i was hoping you may have come back with another idea of how this simulation could be achieved. As you can see we have a solution below but i was wondering whether you had any new thoughts? The solution below works well and was along the same lines as what i was working toward. If you're done with this then that's fine of course, just thought I'd check in!

Comment: Happy new year to you too :) the proposed solution is indeed working well, although I believe may be significantly shortened. I'll try to work something out when time allows, but at least you have a functional solution :)

Comment: @EitanT Great, thanks! I'm happy with the solution I'm using now, just always curious to see other ways that people come up with, i'm constantly amazed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been wondering what kind of solution you would end up with for this problem. From your comment:

> The way i'm thinking now is to have a fixed resolution of segments on one of the rollers(probably the largest) and all the others should be a relative, integer, ratio of this so the segments match as the system rotates.

it seems like you are currently working on a solution of the same type that I have here.

**Note:** There is a copy-friendly version at the end.

Starting out, I have used the structure EitanT used in his answer to the previous question.

```
% # Initial state
C = [0, 0;   % # Roller centers (x, y)
     2, 0;
     2, 4;
     2,-5;
     8, 4;
     8,-5;
     8,-1];
R = [1,1,3,4,3,2,2];    % # Roller radii (r)
N = numel(R);           % # Amount of rollers

% # Draw the rollers
figure, hold on
ang = 0:0.1:(2 * pi);
for i = 1:N
    plot(C(i, 1) + R(i) * cos(ang), C(i, 2) + R(i) * sin(ang))
    text(C(i, 1), C(i, 2), num2str(i))
end
title('Ink rollers'), axis image

% # Find connected rollers
isconn = @(m, n)(sum(([1, -1] * C([m, n], :)) .^ 2) - sum(R([m, n])) .^ 2 < eps);
[Y, X] = meshgrid(1:N, 1:N);
conn = reshape(arrayfun(isconn, X(:), Y(:)), N, N) - eye(N);
```

I used this example to see the difference in the ordering of the connections. This is the produced image of the rollers:

[image: Image of rollers.]

The idea is that roller one is filled with ink and that this ink propagates through the system reaching roller 7 via rollers 3 and 5 or 4 and 6.

I manually set the directions of all the rollers. This step could instead be done automatically by using the connection-matrix `conn`.

```
% # Direction of rotation (clockwise = -1, anticlockwise = 1)
rotDir = [1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1];
```

I then specify the number of bins for the smallest roller and scale up the bins of all the other rollers.

```
% # Number of bins specified for smallest roller
nBins_min = 20;
nBins = round(nBins_min*R/min(R));
```

The next step is to initialize the rollers. I have used a struct to save ink, connections and roller direction in the same variable. The idea is to maintain an ink-value and keep track of connections for each segment of all the rollers. If a segment `jj` of roller `ii` is not connected to an other roller this is represented by a zero in `rollers(ii).connections(jj)`. Otherwise, if it is connected, this cell-element will contain the roller index of the roller it connects to.

```
% # Initialize roller struct
rollers = struct('ink',{},'connections',{},'rotDirection',{});

% # Ink
for ii = 1:N
    rollers(ii).ink = zeros(1,nBins(ii));
end
rollers(1).ink = ones(1,nBins(1));

% # Connections
for ii = 1:N
    rollers(ii).connections = zeros(1,nBins(ii));
end
for ii = 1:N
    for jj = 1:N
        if(ii~=jj)
            if(conn(ii,jj) == 1)
                connInd = getConnectionIndex(C,ii,jj,nBins(ii));
                rollers(ii).connections(connInd) = jj;
            end
        end
    end
end

% # Direction of rotation
for ii = 1:N
    rollers(ii).rotDirection = rotDir(ii);
end
```

I have implemented the function used above `getConnectionIndex()` in the following (quite ugly) way:

```
function connectionIndex = getConnectionIndex(C,ii,jj,nBins)

p1 = C(ii, :);
p2 = C(jj, :);

if(abs(p1(2)-p2(2))<eps)
    if(p2(1)>p1(1))
        angle = 0;
    else
        angle = pi;
    end
elseif(abs(p1(1)-p2(1))<eps)
    if(p2(2)>p1(2))
        angle = pi/2;
    else
        angle = 3*pi/2;
    end
else
    angle = mod( atan((p2(1)-p1(1))/(p2(2)-p1(2))), 2*pi);
end

connectionIndex = 1+floor(nBins*angle/(2*pi));

end
```

The function uses the center points of the rollers to get the corresponding angle of the connection. From this angular value the index of the segment is calculated.

Each time step (a rotation of all segments one step) the average amount of ink on each of the rollers is calculated and saved. This matrix is initialized and the initial ink distribution is calculated and saved.

```
% # Initialize averageAmountOfInk and calculate initial distribution
nTimeSteps = 200;
averageAmountOfInk = zeros(nTimeSteps,N);
for ii = 1:N
    averageAmountOfInk(1,ii) = mean(rollers(ii).ink);
end
```

The following steps are performed for each time step.

```
% # Iterate through timesteps
for tt = 2:nTimeSteps
```

The first roller is filled with ink and all rollers are rotated one step according to their direction of rotation.

```
% # Fill first roller with ink
rollers(1).ink = ones(1,nBins(1));

% # Rotate all rollers
for ii = 1:N
        rollers(ii).ink(:) = ...
            circshift(rollers(ii).ink(:),rollers(ii).rotDirection);
end
```

All roller connections are then updated by finding the matching connection and dividing the ink of these two connections evenly.

```
% # Update all roller-connections
for ii = 1:N
    for jj = 1:nBins(ii)
        if(rollers(ii).connections(jj) ~= 0)
            index1 = rollers(ii).connections(jj);
            index2 = find(ii == rollers(index1).connections);
            ink1 = rollers(ii).ink(jj);
            ink2 = rollers(index1).ink(index2);
            rollers(ii).ink(jj) = (ink1+ink2)/2;
            rollers(index1).ink(index2) = (ink1+ink2)/2;
        end
    end
end
```

As the last step the average amount of ink on the rollers is calculated and after the loop has finished these values are plotted.

```
    % # Calculate average amount of ink on each roller
    for ii = 1:N
        averageAmountOfInk(tt,ii) = mean(rollers(ii).ink);
    end
end

figure
plot(averageAmountOfInk,'b')
xlabel('Timesteps')
ylabel('Ink')
```

Running the code it produces the following plot of the average ink of all the rollers.

For 20 segments of the smallest roller and 60 timesteps we get the following figure:

[image: Ink for 20 segments and 60 timesteps.]

If we run the simulation for 2000 timesteps we can see the convergence towards one as all the rollers fill up with ink.

[image: Ink for 20 segments and 2000 timesteps.]

Copy-friendly version:

```
function averageAmountOfInk = inkRollerModel()
% # Initial state
C = [0, 0;   % # Roller centers (x, y)
     2, 0;
     2, 4;
     2,-5;
     8, 4;
     8,-5;
     8,-1];
R = [1,1,3,4,3,2,2];    % # Roller radii (r)
N = numel(R);           % # Amount of rollers

% # Draw the rollers
figure, hold on
ang = 0:0.1:(2 * pi);
for i = 1:N
    plot(C(i, 1) + R(i) * cos(ang), C(i, 2) + R(i) * sin(ang))
    text(C(i, 1), C(i, 2), num2str(i))
end
title('Ink rollers'), axis image

% # Find connected rollers
isconn = @(m, n)(sum(([1, -1] * C([m, n], :)) .^ 2) - sum(R([m, n])) .^ 2 < eps);
[Y, X] = meshgrid(1:N, 1:N);
conn = reshape(arrayfun(isconn, X(:), Y(:)), N, N) - eye(N);

% # Direction of rotation (clockwise = -1, anticlockwise = 1)
rotDir = [1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1];

% # Number of bins for smallest roller
nBins_min = 20;
nBins = round(nBins_min*R/min(R));

% # Initialize roller struct
rollers = struct('ink',{},'connections',{},'rotDirection',{});

% # Ink
for ii = 1:N
    rollers(ii).ink = zeros(1,nBins(ii));
end
rollers(1).ink = ones(1,nBins(1));

% # Connections
for ii = 1:N
    rollers(ii).connections = zeros(1,nBins(ii));
end
for ii = 1:N
    for jj = 1:N
        if(ii~=jj)
            if(conn(ii,jj) == 1)
                connInd = getConnectionIndex(C,ii,jj,nBins(ii));
                rollers(ii).connections(connInd) = jj;
            end
        end
    end
end

% # Direction of rotation
for ii = 1:N
    rollers(ii).rotDirection = rotDir(ii);
end

% # Initialize averageAmountOfInk and calculate initial distribution
nTimeSteps = 200;
averageAmountOfInk = zeros(nTimeSteps,N);
for ii = 1:N
    averageAmountOfInk(1,ii) = mean(rollers(ii).ink);
end

% # Iterate through timesteps
for tt = 2:nTimeSteps
    % # Fill first roller with ink
    rollers(1).ink = ones(1,nBins(1));

    % # Rotate all rollers
    for ii = 1:N
            rollers(ii).ink(:) = ...
                circshift(rollers(ii).ink(:),rollers(ii).rotDirection);
    end

    % # Update all roller-connections
    for ii = 1:N
        for jj = 1:nBins(ii)
            if(rollers(ii).connections(jj) ~= 0)
                index1 = rollers(ii).connections(jj);
                index2 = find(ii == rollers(index1).connections);
                ink1 = rollers(ii).ink(jj);
                ink2 = rollers(index1).ink(index2);
                rollers(ii).ink(jj) = (ink1+ink2)/2;
                rollers(index1).ink(index2) = (ink1+ink2)/2;
            end
        end
    end

    % # Calculate average amount of ink on each roller
    for ii = 1:N
        averageAmountOfInk(tt,ii) = mean(rollers(ii).ink);
    end
end

figure
plot(averageAmountOfInk,'b')
xlabel('Timesteps')
ylabel('Ink')

end

function connectionIndex = getConnectionIndex(C,ii,jj,nBins)

p1 = C(ii, :);
p2 = C(jj, :);

if(abs(p1(2)-p2(2))<eps)
    if(p2(1)>p1(1))
        angle = 0;
    else
        angle = pi;
    end
elseif(abs(p1(1)-p2(1))<eps)
    if(p2(2)>p1(2))
        angle = pi/2;
    else
        angle = 3*pi/2;
    end
else
    angle = mod( atan((p2(1)-p1(1))/(p2(2)-p1(2))), 2*pi);
end

connectionIndex = 1+floor(nBins*angle/(2*pi));

end
```

**Edit:** Original problem values

```
C = [-276.4, 565.08;...  % # Duct
     -27.82, 616.11;...  % # r2
      41.26, 562.41;...  % # r3
      52.12, 473.07;...  % # r4
     -44.97, 366.25;...  % # ink drum
      137.22, 443.76;... % # r6
      99.32, 362.13;...  % # r7
      141.22, 272.79;... % # r8
      51.67, 237.7;...   % # r9
      173.99, 177.07;... % # r10
     -203.02, 230.52;... % # r11
     -110.9, 213.53;...  % # r12
     -207.33, 131.94;... % # r13
     -187.4, 330.49;...  % # r14
      0,0...             % # Plate cylinder
];% # Roller centres (x, y)

R = [...
95/2,...  % # Duct
80/2,...  % # r2
95/2,...  % # r3
85/2,...  % # r4
208/2,... % # Drum
96/2,...  % # r6
85/2,...  % # r7
112.35/2,... % # r8
81/2,...  % # r9
90/2,...  % # r10
112.35/2,... % # r11
75/2,...  % # r12
86/2,...  % # r13
90/2,...  % # r14
406.5/2 % # Plate
]; % # Roller radii (r)
```

Comment: that is exactly the sort of thing i've been trying to produce!i'm just having a look at it now, the procedure you've followed fits the model perfectly!it may take me a little while to understand the code but i reckon you're comments will be pretty helpful in that regard!i really like the way you've indexed the angle with the segment on the roller, it's clever!thanks so much for your help and interest, and also to EitanT who i know was also interested, i'll let you know how i get on with my 'rotated matrix' version if i figure it out!thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @richyo1000 Glad I could help! Yes I hope the comments help you, if something is still unclear you are very welcome to ask.

Comment: @ user1884905 it works great! there's a couple of things i'd like to ask if i may...When i expand the code to produce the image i posted initially(15 rollers) i hit: ??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in ==> inkRollerModel at 115
                ink2 = rollers(index1).ink(index2);         R and C are both 15 long and i expanded the rotDir to match...any ideas on what else i need to modify?also, how do i access the data in each individual bin?i can't seem to bring up the matrix!thanks!

Comment: @richyo1000 Well, those changes should do it. There might be something wrong with the code. Could you add your values of R, C and rotDir so that I can test it?

Comment: Think i got it, the coordinates and radii i'm using aren't whole integers and the row vectors for Ink don't like it....

Comment: @richyo1000 Great if you got it to work, but I don't really understand where non-integer values caused problems.

Comment: @richyo1000 As for your question about how to access the data: If you want to use the `rollers` data outside the function you can return it like so `function [averageAmountOfInk, rollers] = inkRollerModel()`. If you then call the function in the same way your can view the data by typing for example `rollers(1)` or `rollers(1).ink`.

Comment: thanks for that!i haven't solved the issue, i'm still exceeding the matrix dims somewhere and the same error code as before...

Comment: @richyo1000 Ok, found it. I had not rounded nBins to integer values. I have edited it accordingly. `nBins = round(nBins_min*R/min(R));` instead of `nBins = nBins_min*R/min(R);`.

Comment: Morning, I've been playing around with this for a good few hours now and i have a couple of questions...regarding nBins, is this the variable which holds the number of 'segments' on each roller?I would like to be able to use the largest cylinder (the one at the bottom of the image) to specify how many system revolutions occur. i.e. n revolutions of that cylinder and all the rest rotate a relative amount. I would also like to be able to see how many segments the prgram has calculated for each roller?knowing this i could calculate how many revolutions the system is doing!thanks!

Comment: @richyo1000 Yes, `nBins` is a vector specifying the number of segments of each roller. If you want to be able to examine all variables you could save the function `getConnectionIndex()` as a separate file and remove the function declaration `function averageAmountOfInk = inkRollerModel()`, running the code as a script. This will leave all variables in your workspace.

Comment: thanks very much!I really appreciate the interest you've taken and the amount of effort you've expended on this problem!Still struggling with returning the values(i'm running around 35-50,000 iterations on 14 rollers) but i'll figure that out. The program works well which is the most important aspect! Thanks very much and i hope you have a great (generic) holiday period!

Answer (score 1):

This is really a comment, not an answer.

The approach you and EitanT seem to be converging on seems like an interesting mathematical problem to turn into computer code. But I'm a little skeptical that your mathematical model will lead to an accurate prediction of the behavior of the real physical system. Some problems that I can think of:

1. You talk about an order in which to apply the ink splitting. This kind-of makes sense for an initial pass through the system, but once all rollers have ink it's not clear to me that there is any sensible "order" in which to iterate through the rollers. If more than one roller initially has ink, it really doesn't make sense even for the first pass.
2. Smaller rollers turn more quickly than larger rollers, so making a single iteration of the algorithm correspond to a single revolution of all rollers doesn't really work.
3. Ink is continuously being spread between rollers, so that the height of ink on each roller is a function of the location on the roller.

In other words, there is a lot of complexity in the physical system that you seem to be ignoring. Perhaps that is OK, and this approach captures 90% of what matters. That would surprise me ... but it would also be interesting that such a complicated system could be modeled so easily!

**Added:**

I just realized that in your other question on this topic, the order in which you cycle through the rollers doesn't matter. So the "order of splitting" may be a red herring here.

I'm also sure that you can get the result from a simple matrix multiplication, but haven't yet tried the work out the relvant matrix. But it's probably pretty easy to figure out!

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the input! you have correctly observed that this problem is more complex than i had thought!the roller radii will make a difference due to the ratios. the general aim is for me to gain an understanding of the ratio of ink laid down by the 4 forme rollers (lower in image). the order that the ink splits does actually make a difference since the ink path is effectively split when it reaches the roller in the middle. but you are entirely correct-i have simplified the problem, perhaps a little too much since i still have water emulsification and temp to include eventually!cheers